# Cancel Php script

Tags: php, android

From an Android application, the app will query a php script and look for new messages in MySQL DataBase.
In order to prevent pointless use of the data, I implemented an 'if' statement, to check if the message in database is empty. If the message is empty, it should not answer to the Android application.

My problem & php code:
The if Statement is not detected and it keeps returning data :

```
 <?php
 if($_REQUEST['pass'] == null){
     die("You Are Not Logged In");
 }

 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE pass='".$_REQUEST['pass']."'");
 while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $result1=$e['message'];

    ////Here the Message = 'No Message' but the Scrpit Continue ...

    if($result1 == 'No Message'){
       exit(0);
       die("No Message");
    }
    $output[]=$e;

    print(json_encode($output));

 }   

 if($_REQUEST['status'] != null){
     $sq2="UPDATE $tbl_name SET status='".$_REQUEST['status']."' WHERE  pass='".$_REQUEST['pass']."'";
 $result=mysql_query($sq2);
 }
 mysql_close();


 ?>
```

Comment: change the if($result1 == 'No Message') to 
if(empty($result1))

Comment: You are testing if the literal string "No Message" is the value of the message. I somehow doubt that...

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection. Escape/validate user input before you use it.

Comment: And you should not die, but return valid json. Makes reaction on the clent side much easier.

Comment: same , does no work , in my DataBase , Message = ' ' , is there a Trim function ?

Comment: @Bart like this : if($_REQUEST['pass'] == null){
 die("You Are Not Logged In");
 }

Comment: @Nikita. No. Google "SQL injection" and get up to speed. Also, do not call "die()" in code, it create messy code. Handle errors gracefully.

Comment: my website use only 1 Password to Connect ...

Comment: yes i understand , Thanks for the info @Bart , ill fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not return anything, and the `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns false immediately, skipping over the entire block.

Comment: no , i get the Json Output with all Case , only the Message = ' '

Comment: Well, there you have your answer. The message is empty, it is not `"No Message"`. There is a difference. Use `empty()` to check for that, or `== ""`

Comment: @Nikita. No. And learn to read documentation or at least experiment.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all , problem Solved by using

```
 if($result1 == ' '){
  exit(0);
  die("No Message");}
```

Logcat say : message = null & error parsing Json Data , about SQL Injection , ill take Note ...